# Using a function as a reference starting point

Tags: excel

I have the function `=SUMPRODUCT(MAX(($A$6:A21<>"")*ROW($A$6:A21)))` which returns the last non-blank row in my column/range. How do I use the result (18 in this case) as the starting point in another function (in the same cell). I want to use it to say `=SUM(F18:F30)` but the 18 would be the `SUMPRODUCT` function itself.

Comment: Via substitution? `=SUM(SUMPRODUCT(MAX(($A$6:A21<>"")*ROW($A$6:A21))):F30)`  (I didn't actually try it).

Comment: @RobertHarvey that would return `18` not `F18` to the first cell in the range.  probably will not work.

Comment: Ah, right you are.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use INDEX():

```
=SUM(INDEX(F:F,SUMPRODUCT(MAX(($A$6:A21<>"")*ROW($A$6:A21)))):F30)
```

As an FYI, this can also be done with OFFSET and INDIRECT, but those are volatile functions and should be avoided in mass as too many will slow down the user experience in Excel.

---

Another non array type of formula would be to use MATCH instead of the SUMPRODUCT.

If the values in A are text then we can substitute: `MATCH("zzz",A:A)`

```
=SUM(INDEX(F:F,MATCH("zzz",A:A)):F30)
```

If numbers we substitute: `MATCH(1E+99,A:A)`

```
=SUM(INDEX(F:F,MATCH(1E+99,A:A)):F30)
```

Comment: Thanks so much. The first solution worked perfectly. I did a few minor additions and ended up with `=SUM(INDEX(F:F,SUMPRODUCT(MAX(($A$6:A9<>"")*ROW($A$6:A9)))+1):OFFSET(INDEX(F:F,SUMPRODUCT(MAX(($A$6:A9<>"")*ROW($A$6:A9)))+1))`. Potentially one of the other ways would work more succinctly but I'm happy.